# How do you define boundary of a system in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

When we have a system we can have the surface containing it to be as big as we like assuming there is no other thing included as we make the boundary surface bigger. So what exactly would be the formal definition of a boundary?

For example we consider PdV as work to expand boundary of a system. But how do we precisely say which boundary we are increasing?

Edit:Then how do you get PdV work? Say you have gas in a free space and say we draw a contour which contains the gas completely. Now to do PdV work it means to expand this contour surface in 3-d but lets say rest of space is empty and we choose a bigger "imaginary" container for the gas. Then the work is 0 because the container hasn't become any bigger

Comment: What do you mean “which boundary” there is only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification of the system/boundary are solely at the discretion of the analyst.  You choose whatever boundary is easiest for you to work with.

Comment: Then how do you get PdV work? 

Say you have gas in a free space and say we draw a contour which contains the gas completely. Now to do PdV work it means to expand this contour surface in 3-d but lets say rest of space is empty and we choose a bigger "imaginary" container for the gas. Then the work is 0 because the container hasn't become any bigger

Comment: So, what’s the problem?

Comment: I mean that depending on what boundary I take the work is different

Comment: Are you talking about the boundary of the solid container compared to the pressure at the leading edge of the gas (which is zero)?

Comment: yeah that's one

Comment: In the equation for the work, the P is supposed to be the pressure at the moving boundary where the work is being done.  In the solid container choice, the displacement at the boundary is zero, so no work is done.  In the leading edge of the gas version, the pressure at the leading edge of the gas is zero, so no work is done.  Either way, no work is done on or by  the system.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the answer was looking for, I think this comment should be put in the original answer